# How to insert a value

Tags: matlab, matrix, insert, numbers

I want to insert a number in the following matrix: `n x 1` matrix

```
6
103
104
660
579
750
300
299
300
750
579
661
580
760
302
301
302
760
580
662
581
```

How to I insert it in the middle and shift the remaining numbers? I tried the following code:

```
Idx=[723]; 
c=false(1,length(Element_set2)+length(Idx)); 
c(Idx)=true; 
result=nan(size(c)); 
result(~c)=Element_set2; 
result(c)=8
```

Comment: Did you try figure it out yourself at all? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16958-insert-a-value-into-an-array-after-it-s-created

Comment: Idx=[723];
c=false(1,length(Element_set2)+length(Idx));
c(Idx)=true;
result=nan(size(c));
result(~c)=Element_set2;
result(c)=8

I used this

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things.  Simply find the middle index by finding the length of the array, dividing by 2 and truncating any decimal points, then using simply indexing to update the new matrix.  Supposing that `result` is the column vector that was created by you and `number` is the value you want to insert in the middle, do the following:

```
number = 8; %// Change to suit whatever number you desire
middle = floor(numel(result) / 2);
result = [result(1:middle); number; result(middle+1:end)];
```

In the future, please read this great MATLAB tutorial on indexing directly from MathWorks: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html.  It's a good resource on the kinds of indexing operations one expects from starting out in MATLAB.